# How can I get data alphabetically letter-wise and numeric-wise using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I get data alphabetically letter-wise and numeric-wise using PHP and MySQL?

I want to display my data like this:

> ```
> **0-9      A             B              C           D               E        **
>    1       Apple         Beautiful      Cat         DAD             Ear 
>    2       Ant           Ball           Cart        Doll            Eat
> ```

Please help me approach this using PHP and MySQL.

```
<ul>
    <?php include "config.php";
        $sql4 = mysql_query("select * from categories");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($sql4);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql4)){
     ?>

<li><?php echo $rows['category_name'] ?></li>
<?php } ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: what your code? where is the data coming?

Comment: i have added the code..please check that

Comment: use `order by category_name ASC` on sql query

Comment: please read my question. i hope this is not enough

Comment: Your example is inconsistent. Do you want a descending alphabetical order or ascending?

Comment: not ascending or desinding..i want to display as alphabetically..if value start with "a" related values will display. if value start with "b" related values will display.. see this link. http://www.couponsforzipcodes.com/storedir.html i want display data same like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a 2D array: Let the `$result` be the mysql_result of your query:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $letter = strtolower(substr($row["category_name"],0,1));
  if(is_numeric($letter)) $letter = "0-9";
  if(!isset($data[$letter])) $data[$letter] = array();
  $data[$letter][] = $row["category_name"];
}
```

and then iterate it to produce the table you want:

```
foreach($data as $column=>$values) {
  // $column contains the first letter (or 0-9)
  foreach($values as $value) {
    // $value contains category_name
  }
}
```

I hope you can finish it from this point, since this site is not supposed to solve all the problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..could you please describe more how to display? according to my code

Comment: Thanks again..So i have to display data like <?php echo $value['category_name'];?> am i correct?

Comment: No - see my update. I believe you can finish it from this point.

Comment: alright. for numeric it is ok.. but alphabetically how to devide?

Comment: see this link. http://www.couponsforzipcodes.com/storedir.html i want display data same like this

Comment: You should think about the double foreach a little more - try to display the $column and $value as the comments suggest. The last thing you need to do is to wrap the values in HTML, like `<div>$column</div>`.

Comment: ok if i want only started with "a" letter values.. how i have to display?

Comment: use `foreach($data["a"] as $value)` instead of the double cycle

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot.. iam working on it. if this works fine i will give you right mark.. Thanks

Comment: Hey Dude Thanks it is working..you saves me days of time..thank you

Comment: @RajuReddy: glad to be helpful. Enjoy the summer holidays :-)

Comment: I got one issue in this code..  For alphabetical letters it is working fine for me. But i have added foreach($data["0-9"] as $value) { echo "$value"} But getting errors. it is not passing the values.. is there any errors behind it?

Comment: The key is lazy-created on the first item. If you don't have any 0-9 record, `$data["0-9"]` is null and can't be iterated. To avoid errors, use `if(!empty($data["0-9"])) foreach($data["0-9"] as $value) ...` If it's not the case, post the exact error including the line.

Answer (score 0):

update skills to PDO as mysql will not work soon.

```
    <?php include "config.php";
        $sql4 = mysql_query("select * from categories order by category_name ASC");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($sql4);
        while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql4)){

    $l = $row['category_name'][0]; // first letter/number
    $category_list[$l][]= $row['category_name'];
}
```

you will have to design this bit how ever you want yourself.

```
<ul>
<?php
if(is_array($category_list)){
foreach($category_list as $k=>$v) {
    echo "<li>$k</li>"; // letter/number

    foreach($v as $cat) {
      echo "<li>$cat</li>"; // category name
  }

  }
}
?>
</ul>
```